# How to make hyperlink shell reference shift as its copied

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm wondering whether there's any way to make hyperlink shell references shift with folders. For example, I have the hyperlink `=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000313", "Link")`. If I copy it down, is there any way to automatically increment the folder number by one, resulting in the following as it's filled down?

```
=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000314", "Link")
=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000315", "Link")
=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000316", "Link")
=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000317", "Link")
=HYPERLINK("NTB\0000000318", "Link")
```

I would like a worksheet-function solution that does this automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
=HYPERLINK("NTB\"&TEXT(ROWS($1:313),"000000000"),"Link")
```

`ROWS($1:313)` counts the number of rows in the range `$1:313`. It will equal 313 in the first row where you enter this. As you fill down, the 313 will be incremented, so in the next row this part of the formula will be `ROWS($1:314)`, which returns 314.

The `TEXT` function wrapper takes this number and reformats it as a 9-digit string with padding zeros on the left. This string is concatenated to the `"NTB\"` part of the shell reference.